# Hibernate 3 - Is a One-To-One Component Join is Lazy by Default

Tags: hibernate

I tried reading Hibernate documentation.[Hibernate One-To-One](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone)

Fetch is optional - defaults to "select", and lazy is optional - and defaults to "proxy". So, if I do not supply either of them, will it default to "eager fetching" and not causing lazy instantiation exception?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html): "By default, Hibernate3 uses lazy select fetching for collections and lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults make sense for most associations in the majority of applications."

So yes, if you don't explicitly set to eager, it should default to lazy.

Answer (score 1):

*lazy is optional - and defaults to "proxy"*

says it all. it defaults to lazyloading proxies instead of lazy none. So i would assume it does load lazy instead of eager

Comment: Then if fetch is optional and defaults to Select, will not the data be fetched eagerly? May be I am just not getting the idea.

Comment: fetch tells hibernate how it should get the data when needed. either through eager loading or lazy loading